# getting to a virtual desktop with different shortcuts and files on it than the base desktop

Tags: desktop, desktop-customization

I have a very cluttered desktop, with many shortcuts and files on it.

When I open up a new W10 virtual desktop the same icons and files appear on the virtual desktop as on the original. If I delete a shortcut on the new virtual desktop it gets removed from the original too.

Is there a way to open up a virtual desktop and manage the shortcuts and files on it independently from the original?

My goal is to make a video showing some software on my desktop, but so far the only way I found to clear the slate on the desktop so I have an uncluttered screen to record from is to move all the shortcuts and files off to another monitor, and then later when I'm done move them back.

Unfortunately, however, the monitor sizes are different there are shortcuts on the other monitor already as well, so moving things back and forth is this way is messy, problematic and time-consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this is not currently possible in windows 10 virtual desktops. Virtual desktops are only meant for ease of multitasking, and apps open in one desktop don't appear on another. And all files in your desktop is stored in C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop folder, changes you make affect there and across all opened virtual desktops.

Comment: thank you - looks like a good niche product to develop for someone smarter than I